# Oracle Apex: DA That Will Fire On Close of Modal Dialog?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I have a pretty ordinary single-page Oracle Apex application.  For my main-page template, I just started from a blank page.

Under certain conditions in this Apex application, based on end-user entry, I have processing defined which branches to another **Modal Dialog** page in the application.

This Modal Dialog has two buttons.  As desired, my application successfully sets session state on the main page depending on which button the user selects:  that all works.  Either button also goes so far as to close this Modal Dialog.

My problem is, back on the main page, I am looking for a Dynamic-Action-type event that will fire when my Modal Dialog closes, so I can attach a little JavaScript (`.setFocus()`) to it.  However, I cannot find any main-page Dynamic Action to fire upon the closing of my Modal Dialog.  I've tried every kind of Dynamic Action on the main page I can think of, with an Action of "Execute JavaScript Code", and, as part of my testing, a simple

`alert("here");`

for the code snippet, but the JavaScript never fires.

Particularly, I've tried setting a DA on the main page's 'Dialog Closed' event, for the main-page's region from which the Modal Dialog redirect took place, but this event does not fire on my Modal Dialog closure.

I'm an Apex noob, so I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.

Is there a way to fire my custom JS on the main page after closing a Modal Dialog?  I threw up a simple app [here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=91122:1).  (apexdemo/apexdemo).  I'm trying to find a way to execute JS code within my main page, after clicking the "Return" button on the Modal Dialog.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to use the item that triggered the Modal dialog. I think you have to set it for the button 'Modal' in the 'simple app'.

Comment: Tebbe, did you still need help with this? Did you see Ian's answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way.
On the main page in Page Designer click the Dynamic Actions tab on the left. Then right click the Dialog Closed Event and click Create Dynamic Action:

[image]

Change the Name to something meaningful, change the Selection Type to JavaScript Expression then put "window" as the JavaScript Express:

[image]

Now click on the Refresh Action on the left and change the Action to Execute JavaScript Code then add your code:

[image]

Now if you open a modal page from the page with this new Dynamic Action, then close the modal page with the a Close Dialog Dynamic Action then it will fire your JavaScript.

Kind regards.